# PFUser Relation - Parse cloud

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am trying to get the objects in the Deal relation of User table so that I can change the value in of that particular reference. I am trying to do this using PFCloud since this involves changing a user's attributes/relation without logging in.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("redeemDeal", function(request, response) {
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
query.equalTo("objectId", request.params.userObjectId);
query.find({
    useMasterKey: true
}).then(function(user) {
  //Found the right user.
  //This is where the JS fails. Cant find the relation
    var dealRelation = user.relation("deals");
    var dealquery = dealRelation.query();
    dealquery.equalTo("objectId", request.params.dealObjectId);
    //trying to find the deal from the relation
    dealquery.find().then(function(deal) {
            deal.setIsRedeemed(true);
            dealRelation.add(deal);
            //Adding that deal back to the relation with redeemed as yes.
            dealRelation.save().then(function(object) {
                    response.success(dealRelation);
                },
                function(error) {
                    response.error(error);
                }
            );
        },
        function(error) {

        });
});
```

});
 I get this error back. Can someone please advise. Thanks

```
TestApp[72316:2635281] Error: TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'relation'
at main.js:12:33
at e (Parse.js:2:6486)
at Parse.js:2:5935
at Array.forEach (native)
at Object.x.each.x.forEach [as _arrayEach] (Parse.js:1:664)
at c.extend.resolve (Parse.js:2:5886)
at null.<anonymous> (Parse.js:2:6565)
at e (Parse.js:2:6486)
at Parse.js:2:7239
at g (Parse.js:2:6976) (Code: 141, Version: 1.2.18)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the data type in the `Deals` column of your database is a Pointer. In your initial query for the user, if you want to include the object stored in that pointer, you should write:

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
query.equalTo("objectId", request.params.userObjectId);
query.include("Deals");
```

That will include the `Deals` object with the user object when your query returns successfully and save you from having to run another query to get the deal. You can also `console.log(JSON.stringify(user));` in the callback of your first query to see what is actually being returned to help better diagnose what is causing the error.

Comment: dstefanis.. it stopped giving that error and now gives this
 Error: {"code":102,"message":"field deals cannot be included because it is not a pointer to another object"} (Code: 141, Version: 1.2.18)

and deals ia relation. i dont want to change the main table's values. just want to change the reference

Comment: ok, it sounds like my answer might only work for pointers and you're using a relation. Did you try `console.log` on the user object? What did it print out or is it not even allowing you to upload the file?

Comment: well..if i remove the relation code..and run it..it prints out the user details in the console..
looks like.. the reference column should NOT be treated like an instance..